# Innermost For Loop Not Reaching Last Iteration - Modulus Operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have some nested for loops below that I want to work like the following.
What I'm doing with them is using an array of dates and an array of items, I section the dates into sets of 10, then I push the items onto that list of 10 dates, going back to the start until I run out of items. Then I move to the next set of 10 dates etc.

My loops explained:

The first for loop creates a section of an array (dateSpan) in order to move through a larger array(dateList) in sections. In this case, dateSpan comes out to 10 items.

The second for loop iterates through an array of items (frequent).

The third for loop iterates through the section of dates(dateSpan) continuously until the item list ends.

Currently, the outer most loop and the middle loop are functioning as intended.

The issue I'm having is with the third/innermost for loop. It iterates through the first 9 items, but not the 10th. I understand this is because for example k+1 equals 10, and divided by dateSpan.length which also equals 10, has a remainder of 0, and therefore returns to the start of the array before reaching the 10th item.

This means the 10th date in each section has no items included in that row of the array. It also means that the items are not distributed the way they should be since those rows are not utilized.

```
  for (i=0; i<(dateList.length/freqSpan); i++){
   //establishing the date section to loop through (10 days in this example)
   //freqSpan = 10

    var spanStart = i*freqSpan;
    var spanEnd = spanStart+freqSpan;
    var dateSpan = dateList.slice(spanStart,spanEnd);

    if(dateSpan.length == 0){
      break;
    }

    for(j=0; j<frequent.length;j++){
      for(k=spanStart; (k+1) % dateSpan.length; k++){  
        
        if (frequent[j] != undefined){

          dateList[k].push(frequent[j]);

        }
        else {
 
          dateList[k].push("");
  
        }

        j++;
          
      }  
    }
  }
```

I don't feel I fully understand the modulo operator or complex nested for loops quite well, at least in this case, so I've tried a few options like K+2, etc but that also doesnt work, I believe since that starts the next loop at a different position and results in multiple unused dates instead of just the 10th.

This is the console log for the 8th, 9th, and 10th rows in the section to better visualize

```
//row 8
[ Wed Aug 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    '' ],
//row 9
 [ Thu Sep 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'item11',
    'item12',
    'item13',
    'item14',
    'item15',
    'item16',
    '' ],
//row 10
  [ Fri Sep 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) ],
//row 11
 [ Mon Sep 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'item17',
    'item18',
    'item19',
    'item20',
    'item21',
    'item22',
    'item23'],
```

In the example, the 10th row should have items 17-23 or whatever until the list completes, but shouldn't be empty like that if working as intended. The example is illustrative only since the items are actually chronological in the columns, not in rows.

Do you have some suggestions for reaching the last row in dateSpan? Everything I've tried makes it either skip the inner for loops altogether, or skips multiple dates in ways I don't fully understand. If there's any other changes you'd suggest to this code in general, I'd appreciate it as I'm self taught and not really certain on best practices etc.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `<` instead of `%`. `%` will cause the loop to run at most one time.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for commenting. That's what I originally had, however I experience the opposite when I run the script. Using `(k+1)< dateSpan.length` causes it to loop only once through the section, and `%` causes it to loop through each section multiple times until I reach the end of the Frequent item list. The only issue is it's not reaching that last row in the dateSpan section for some reason

Comment: So try `<=`. `%` doesn't make any sense here

Comment: How about `k < spanEnd`?

Comment: @johndee31415 Thank you!! This worked! I couldn't wrap my head around what was wrong, but didnt think to use spanEnd. If you write this as an answer I'll select it!